# DBT Airflow DAG JSON overrides using Kubernetes operator

Tags: kubernetes, jinja2, airflow, kubernetes-pod, dbt

Created a DAG to access overrides. Below are the commands that are passed in the overrides.
`JSON on Airflow UI : {"dbt_command": ["products", "--full-refresh"]}`

The commands are accessible but its in the format of list string. How could I convert or remove the type string and list square braces at "products" and "--full-refresh?

**Output in Airflow logs:**

`['dbt', 'run', '--select', "['products', '--full-refresh']", '--target', 'stage']`

**Expected Output:**

`['dbt', 'run', '--select', 'products', '--full-refresh', '--target', 'stage']`

**Original Code:**

```
Dbt_overrides_Reporting_Task = KubernetesPodOperator(
    namespace="airflow",
    service_account_name="airflow",
    task_id="overrides",
    image="dbt-snowflake:latest",
    cmds = ["dbt", "run", "--select", "{{dag_run.conf.get('dbt_command', '') if dag_run}}" , "--target", "stage"],
    provide_context=True,
    dag_run_conf_overrides_params=True,
    dag = dag,
    is_delete_operator_pod=True,
    name=f"{DAG_NAME}.dag",
    secrets=[keys_env],
    configmaps=[f"{CHART_NAME}-configmap"],
    in_cluster=True,
    get_logs=True,
    env_vars={
        "ENV": os.environ["ENV"],
    },
)
```

Could anyone please help me with this issue? How can i convert the dag_run.conf jinja template at cmds in kubernetes operator ?

Comment: Can you post the contents of `dag_run.conf` that you're passing in when running the DAG?

Comment: contents of `dag_run.conf` is `{"dbt_command": ["products", "--full-refresh"]}`

Answer (score 0):

```
cmds = ["dbt", "run", "--select", "{{dag_run.conf.get('dbt_command_part1', '') if dag_run}}", "{{dag_run.conf.get('dbt_command_part2', '') if dag_run}}" , "--target", "stage"],
```

and supply {"dbt_command_part1": "products", "dbt_command_part2":  "--full-refresh"]}

should solve your issue.